# I try to use MouseWheel to zoom image but It not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to make zoom function with mouse wheel but When I start my project zoom function is not work

My Code

Form1.Designer.cs

```
        this.Panel4.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Panel4.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Panel4.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
        this.Panel4.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
        this.Panel4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 353);
        this.Panel4.Name = "Panel4";
        this.Panel4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1163, 365);
        this.Panel4.TabIndex = 7;
```

Form1.cs

Add MouseWheel Event

```
 InitializeComponent();
 Panel4.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Panel4_MouseWheel);
```

When I roll mouse wheel this function is active

```
private void Panel4_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Zoom!!");
        this.Focus();
        // or Panel4.Focus();
        if (e.Delta < 120 && zoomIn_zoomOut > 1)
        {
            zoomIn_zoomOut--;
            zoom_len -= zoomIn_zoomOut;
        }
        else if (e.Delta >= 120)
        {
            zoomIn_zoomOut++;
            zoom_len += zoomIn_zoomOut;
        }

        factor = new Size(zoomIn_zoomOut, 1);
        zoom_pic(factor, e);
    }


void zoom_pic(Size scale, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        // Calculate and zoom Picture
    }
```

Expect result

```
Zoom!!
```

Real result

```
(show nothing)
```

**Can you tell me What is problem of this code ? I have no way to solve it.**

Thank you very much

Comment: How do you zoom the picture though..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zooming of an image using mousewheel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163846/zooming-of-an-image-using-mousewheel)

Comment: @Haytam I'm not sure but I try to do like that topic but It's not work.