# I can't get the correct coordinate of an image with mouse over C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, mouseover, resolution, mousemove

This is my first question ever on Stackoverflow. So I hope it for the best answer.

I want to get correct X and Y coordinate of an Image with mouse over Event (WFA .NET Framework). 
[Take a look at my cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqkKh.jpg)

The coordinate should be somewhere between 500 for X and 427 for Y, but I only get as I posted. I already maxed out the scroll. And I think the image resolution is correct, [here's the image properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmDym.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
private void pbInput_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {        
mouseX.Text = e.X.ToString();
mouseY.Text = e.Y.ToString();
}
```

And I have a plan to zooming the image for the future, so I put "auto scroll" panel below the picture box.

Could you help me? Thank you so much.

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: What is the size of your picture box? What is the SizeMode?

Comment: The Size is 314, 314. And the SizeMode is **Normal**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting picturebox inside panel
set panel to:

```
this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

and picturebox to

```
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

this will allow panel to have scroll bars and picturebox will have its full size adjusted to actual picture size

Comment: Thank you. Apparently is working, but if I working on zoomed image, the coordinates still incorrect. [I'm using this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164138/8903813) for zooming